# Problems due to extra whitespace in boost::lexical cast

Tags: c++, boost

This causes problems due to extra whitespace:

```
std::string t("3.14 ");
double d = boost::lexical_cast<double> (t);
```

So, I wrote this

```
template<typename T> 
T string_convert(const std::string& given)
{
  T output;
  std::stringstream(given) >> output;
  return output;
}

double d = string_convert<double> (t);
```

What can be the problems with this? Is there a better way? Much prefer to use lexical cast

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that your code isn't always correct. If you do `string_convert<double>("a")`, for example, the read will fail and you'll return `output` uninitialized, leading to undefined behavior.

You can do this:

```
template<typename T> 
T string_convert(const std::string& given)
{
  T output;
  if (!(std::stringstream(given) >> output))
    throw std::invalid_argument(); // check that extraction succeeded

  return output;
}
```

Note the only difference between the above code and Boost's is that Boost also checks to make sure nothing is left in the stream. What you should do, though, is just trim your string first:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>

std::string t("3.14 ");
boost::algorithm::trim(t); // get rid of surrounding whitespace

double d = boost::lexical_cast<double>(t);
```

Comment: Crucially, the above `string_convert` template doesn't just conveniently ignore whitespace: if also ignores trailing non-whitespace that may well indicate an invalid value.  The `trim` is definitely more robust, or you can change `string_convert` ala `char c; std::stringstream ss(given); if (!(ss >> output) || (ss >> c)) ...`.

Comment: If you want a conversion function which ignores trailing whitespace, you should do something like: `std::stringstream s(given); if (!(s >> output >> ws) || s.get() != EOF) throw ...`

Answer (score 3):

`Boost::lexical_cast` considers an attempted conversion successful *only* if the entire input is converted into the output. I.e., it's basically like your `string_convert`, except that just before `return output`, it checks whether there's anything left in the `stringstream`, and if there is, it considers the conversion "failed", and throws an exception.